# Limiting text box entry to numbers or numpad only - no special characters

Tags: powershell, textbox

I have a small program which accepts an integer and converts it to `DateTime`. However, I try to use `KeyCode` to only allow numbers from both keyboard and numpad, and eliminate the special characters and letters. My code is allowing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num</kbd> to enter those special characters. How do eliminate them from being entered?

```
$FromDateText.Add_KeyDown({KeyDown})
$ToDateText.Add_KeyDown({KeyDown})  #TextBox

Function KeyDown()
{
    if ($FromDateText.Focused -eq $true -or $ToDateText.Focused -eq $true)
    {
        if ($_.KeyCode -gt 47 -And $_.KeyCode -lt 58 -or $_.KeyCode -gt 95 -and
            $_.KeyCode -lt 106 -or $_.KeyCode -eq 8)
        {
            $_.SuppressKeyPress = $false 
        }
        else
        {
            $_.SuppressKeyPress = $true  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, how about just adding `-and -not $_.Shift` to your second `If` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of intercepting the `KeyDown` event, I'd simply just remove any non-digit character from the `TextBox` every time the [`TextChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) is raised:

```
$ToDateText.add_TextChanged({
    # Check if Text contains any non-Digits
    if($tbox.Text -match '\D'){
        # If so, remove them
        $tbox.Text = $tbox.Text -replace '\D'
        # If Text still has a value, move the cursor to the end of the number
        if($tbox.Text.Length -gt 0){
            $tbox.Focus()
            $tbox.SelectionStart = $tbox.Text.Length
        }
    }
})
```

Way easier than trying to infer the input value from Key event args

Comment: I still want to use backspace or delete or the arrow keys(i still have to code  arrow and delete), which is why i was using the keydown

Comment: You can still use arrows and backspace and delete all you want with this approach - only thing the code in my answer does is ensure that the value in the text box only consists of numerical digits every time the input value *changes* (not on every single key press).

Comment: Another upside to this approach is that a user can still copy-paste a formatted date time string (for example "15:03 01/12/2013") and the special characters will automatically be removed (so you end up with the value "150301122013" instead)