# Don't allow typing characters like: .,:+

Tags: powershell

I have a Textbox in Powershell and I wondering how to prevent user from typing signs like `.`,`:`, key combination like: `AAA` etc?

I tried with Regex, but I want it to be dynamic - so when user type e.g. `.` it doesn't appear in TextBox. Probably, the MaskedTextBox can be a solution, but I don't want to specify how many characters user can type e.g. using `AA` - user can write 2 letters.

My goal is to make typing some signs and letter combination impossible. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain with more details what kind of input is allowed and what's not? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's better a way than filtering the input?

Comment: Thanks for your responce. Allowed: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and "-". Don't allowed: other signs like ".", ">", "/" etc. and 4 key combination: "ASD", CVB" "AAA", "BBB".

Comment: [Like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404631/limiting-text-box-entry-to-numbers-or-numpad-only-no-special-characters/38404928#38404928) You just have to replace `'\D'` with a regex pattern satisfying the conditions you just listed

Comment: Yes, I created something based on that comment and it works. Thank you very much for your tips!